# How to list the details of VLAN's using C#.Net

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I need to get the details of VLANs (Virtual LAN) with Name, shortname and description using C#.Net. Is it possible. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I searched regarding this requirement, but didn't get anything.

Answer (score 1):

Have no good solution for this case. 
But can use "**System.Net.NetworkInformation**" to get NetworkInterface() via Name,Description, NetworkInterfaceType and ID.

```
  NetworkInterface[] adapters = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
        foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in adapters)
        {
            IPInterfaceProperties properties = adapter.GetIPProperties();
            Console.WriteLine(adapter.Description);
            Console.WriteLine(adapter.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(adapter.NetworkInterfaceType);
            Console.WriteLine(adapter.ID);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: Yeah that looks to be the case.   Other solution might be to Process Exec a shell command:    ip -d link show dev eth0.100 | grep 'vlan protocol'